# Error when creating rabbitmq broker in aws amazonmq

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq

Error when creating rabbitmq broker in aws amazon

I created a single instance of RabbitMQ in single AZ in AWS AmazonMQ. I didn't give any special options, I only enabled "Cloudwatch Log".

But when the broker loads, the Cloudwatch Log is full of errors like:

```
2023-07-29 12:59:08.859969+00:00 [notice] <0.15265.0> TLS server: In state hello at tls_handshake.erl:366 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Protocol Version
or
2023-07-29 15:42:19.283750+00:00 [notice] <0.24445.0> TLS server: In state hello at tls_record.erl:564 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Unexpected Message
```

[image]

The error occurs the first time the broker is loaded or reloaded, and continues to appear at unknown intervals thereafter. Errors that appear during load can be ignored, but errors that occur continuously interfere with monitoring.

The broker engine version is 3.10.20.

There is no problem in just using it, but there are difficulties in monitoring.

Am I the only one experiencing this phenomenon?